# Is there a way to find questions with more than 10 downvotes?

Tags: support

This is for learning purposes: finding questions with many downvotes can help to learn how NOT to ask a question in SO and avoid common mistakes (like making a question and not showing any effort for finding the solution in advance).

Comment: I like the sentiment, but I don't think this approach is gonna work. Stuff with 10+ net downvotes are often soooo obviously bad that you can't learn anything from them.

Comment: I'll second what @Mysticial said - you're likely going to learn a lot more from seeking out highly **upvoted** questions, and trying to identify what they did *right*. It's not that hard not to post an **awful** question, it takes more nuance to post a really great one.

Comment: You might do better to just hang out in the "Newest" tab and looking at what gets downvoted quickly. Another option is to use "closed:1" which will find all closed questions, sort that by "Newest", and look at questions that have been put on hold. This has the benefit of showing you bad questions that also have a reason it's considered bad added to the post.

Comment: @Mysticial you got me: -10 question usually are terrible. My original question had "a lot" instead of "more than 10", but "a lot" is rather subjetive.

Comment: If you want to see the dregs of undeleted questions, simply sort the question list by votes and go to the last page.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce you're right: but there are several steps involved: you have to go to the "complete list of questions" link down below SO main page, click "votes" tab and go to the latest pages (OMG, I found questions with almost -100 votes!. I chose the latest pages because it was easier). The search query in BradleyDotNET's answer is more straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following search:

> score:..-10 is:question

The ".." says look for the range **under** the argument. Here is a link for your convienence: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-10+is%3Aquestion

Note that this isn't *quite* the same as "10 downvotes" but it is 10 *net* downvotes. Also note that these questions get cleaned up regularly, so there aren't all that many (just 1000) and posts that are here today may be gone tomorrow :)